# ClusteredMapView - Android - Continuously re-rendering and making the map very slow. Works fine in iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

Does anyone know off-hand if react-native-maps-super-cluster is just kind of slow on android, or if there is something in my code that is making it slow? It works fine on iOS, and then I tried on Android, and now it hardly responds. It will keep flipping between zoom levels and regions, etc.

Here is what I have

```
    renderMap = () => {
        var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

        return (
        <View style={FULL}>
            {/* Cluster Map Example */}
            {!this.state.connection && (
                <Text
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: palette.angry,
                        color: palette.offWhite,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignContent: 'center',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }}
                >
                    Bad Connection
                </Text>
            )}
            <ClusteredMapView
                radius={100}
                edgePadding={{ top: 10, left: 30, bottom: 10, right: 30 }}
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    width: width,
                    height: height
                }}
                data={this.state.markers}
                renderMarker={this.renderMarker}
                renderCluster={this.renderCluster}
                initialRegion={this.getInitialState()}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
                ref={(ref) => (this.mapView = ref)}
                clusterPressMaxChildren={10000}
            >
                {/* 
        Markers rendered as children of ClusteredMapView are not taken in account by the clustering feature,
        they will just act as they were rendered within a normal react-native-maps instance

                <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 44.710968, longitude: 10.640131 }} pinColor={'#65bc46'} />
                */}
            </ClusteredMapView>
            <Modal
                isVisible={false}
                onBackdropPress={this.toggleModal}
                onSwipeComplete={this.toggleModal}
                swipeDirection='left'
            >
                <View style={MODAL}>
                    <Text style={TEXT}>I am the modal content!</Text>
                </View>
            </Modal>
            <ActionSheet
                styles={actionSheetStyles}
                ref={(o) => (this.ActionSheet = o)}
                title={this.state.actionSheetTitle}
                options={[ 'Cancel', 'Detail', 'Directions', 'Remove Donor' ]}
                cancelButtonIndex={0}
                onPress={(index) => {
                    switch (index) {
                        case 1:
                            this.goToDonorDetail();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            console.tron.log('Directions');
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            this.removeDonor();
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.tron.log('Default');
                    }
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

    renderMarker = (pin) => {
            console.tron.log('Rendering Marker');
            let index = this.state.markers.findIndex((lead) => lead.key === pin.key);

            if (index >= 0) {
                return (
                    <Marker
                        identifier={`pin-${pin.id}`}
                        key={pin.key}
                        //icon={mapMarker}
                        radius={70}
                        coordinate={pin.location}
                        pinColor={
                            pin.memberType === 'New Business' ? (
                                palette.angry
                            ) : pin.memberType === 'Rejoiner' ? (
                                palette.green
                            ) : (
                                palette.blue
                            )
                        }
                        onPress={() => this.markerOnPress(pin)}
                        calloutOffset={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    >
                        {/*<Image source={require('./Map-Marker.png')} style={{ height: 35, width: 35 }} />*/}
                        <Callout
                            alphaHitTest
                            tooltip={false}
                            onPress={(e) => {
                                /*if (
                                e.nativeEvent.action === 'marker-inside-overlay-press' ||
                                e.nativeEvent.action === 'callout-inside-press'
                            ) {
                                return;
                            }*/

                                this.showActionSheet(pin);
                            }}
                            style={styles.customView}
                        >
                            <View style={MODAL}>
                                <Text>
                                    {pin.firstName} {pin.lastName}
                                </Text>
                                <Text>{pin.companyName}</Text>
                                <Text>{pin.address}</Text>
                                <Text>
                                    {pin.city}, {pin.state} {pin.zip}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </Callout>
                    </Marker>
                );
            } else return null;
        };

        renderCluster = (cluster, onPress) => {
        const pointCount = cluster.pointCount,
            coordinate = cluster.coordinate,
            clusterId = cluster.clusterId;
        const clusteringEngine = this.mapView.getClusteringEngine(),
            clusteredPoints = clusteringEngine.getLeaves(clusterId, pointCount);

        let rejoiners = [];
        let leads = [];
        let renewals = [];
        clusteredPoints.map((point) => {
            let item = point.properties.item;
            if (item.opportunityType) {
                if (item.opportunityType === 'Rejoiner') {
                    rejoiners.push(item);
                } else if (item.opportunityType === 'Renewal') {
                    renewals.push(item);
                }
            } else {
                leads.push(item);
            }
        });

        let keys = [ 'rejoiners', 'renewals', 'leads' ];
        let values = [ rejoiners.length, renewals.length, leads.length ];
        const colors = [ 'green', 'blue', 'red' ];

        const data = keys.map((key, index) => {
            return {
                key,
                value: values[index],
                svg: { fill: colors[index] }
                //arc: { outerRadius: 80 + '%', padAngle: label === key ? 0.1 : 0 },
                //onPress: () => this.setState({ selectedSlice: { label: key, value: values[index] } })
            };
        });

        /*<PieChart style={{ height: 200 }} outerRadius={'80%'} innerRadius={'15%'} data={data} />*/

        return (
            <Marker identifier={`cluster-${clusterId}`} coordinate={coordinate} onPress={onPress}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100
                    }}
                >
                    <Svg width={100} height={100}>
                        <PieChart style={{ height: 100 }} outerRadius={'100%'} innerRadius={'0%'} data={data} />
                        <View
                            style={{
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                position: 'absolute',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center'
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text
                                style={{
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    textAlignVertical: 'center'
                                }}
                            >
                                {clusteredPoints.length}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </Svg>
                </View>
            </Marker>
        );
    };


    componentDidMount = async () => {
        console.tron.log('Component Mounting');
        this.subs = [ this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => this.componentDidFocus()) ];
        NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {
            console.tron.log('Connection type', state.type);
            console.tron.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);
        });

        const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
            console.log('Connection type', state.type);
            console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);
            console.tron.log('Connected to Internet: ', state.isInternetReachable);
            if (!state.isConnected || !state.isInternetReachable) {
                this.setState({ connection: false });
            } else {
                this.setState({ connection: true });
            }
        });

        unsubscribe();

        /**
         * { location: { latitude: 41.8962667,longitude: 11.3340056 } }
         */
        const { filterStore, donorStore, navigation, opportunityStore } = this.props;
        navigation.setParams({ mapIcon: this.mapIcon, navigateToFilters: () => this.navigateToFilters() });

        await donorStore.getLeads().catch((e) => console.tron.log(e.message));
        await opportunityStore.getOpportunities().catch((e) => console.tron.log(e.message));

        let donors = filterStore.filteredLeads;
        let rejoiners = opportunityStore.allRejoiners;
        let renewals = opportunityStore.allRenewals;

        this.setMarkers(donors, rejoiners, renewals);

        this.setState({ region: this.getInitialState(), mounted: true });
    };

setMarkers = (donors, rejoiners, renewals) => {
        const { filterStore } = this.props;
        let filtered = filterStore.filteredLeads;

        try {
            //filtered.forEach((donor) => console.tron.log(donor));
        } catch (e) {
            console.tron.log(e.message);
        }

        let markers = [];
        if (donors && donors.length > 0) {
            donors.forEach((donor, index) => {
                markers.push({
                    id: donor.id,
                    key: donor.key,
                    location: {
                        latitude: donor.location._lat,
                        longitude: donor.location._long
                    },
                    index: index,
                    memberType: donor.memberType,
                    companyName: donor.companyName,
                    firstName: donor.firstName,
                    lastName: donor.lastName,
                    address1: donor.votingAddress.address1,
                    address2: donor.votingAddress.address2,
                    city: donor.votingAddress.city,
                    state: donor.votingAddress.state,
                    zip: donor.votingAddress.zip
                });
            });
        }

        if (rejoiners && rejoiners.length > 0) {
            rejoiners.forEach((rejoiner, index) => {
                let donor = rejoiner.donor;
                markers.push({
                    ...rejoiner,
                    id: donor.id,
                    location: {
                        latitude: donor.location._lat,
                        longitude: donor.location._long
                    },
                    index: index,
                    memberTypeDonor: donor.memberType,
                    companyName: donor.companyName,
                    firstName: donor.firstName,
                    lastName: donor.lastName,
                    address1: donor.votingAddress.address1,
                    address2: donor.votingAddress.address2,
                    city: donor.votingAddress.city,
                    state: donor.votingAddress.state,
                    zip: donor.votingAddress.zip,
                    memberType: 'Rejoiner'
                });
            });
        }

        if (renewals && renewals.length > 0) {
            renewals.forEach((renewal, index) => {
                let donor = renewal.donor;

                markers.push({
                    ...renewal,
                    id: donor.id,
                    location: {
                        latitude: donor.location._lat,
                        longitude: donor.location._long
                    },
                    index: index,
                    memberTypeDonor: donor.memberType,
                    companyName: donor.companyName,
                    firstName: donor.firstName,
                    lastName: donor.lastName,
                    address1: donor.votingAddress.address1,
                    address2: donor.votingAddress.address2,
                    city: donor.votingAddress.city,
                    state: donor.votingAddress.state,
                    zip: donor.votingAddress.zip,
                    memberType: 'Renewal'
                });
            });
        }

        this.setState({ markers });
    };
```

I know there are some optimizations that I can make. I tried to make them in a previous attempt to fix the bouncing around, but eventually just reverted my code to try again, and have no included the improvements again. Any help is appreciated.

Updated ClusterMarker to be its own class and added tracksViewChanges.

```
    export class ClusterMarker extends React.Component<ClusterMarkerProps, {}> {
    state = {
        tracksViewChanges: true
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any) {
        console.tron.log('Component Will Receive Props');
        if (!isEqual(this.props, nextProps)) {
            this.setState(() => ({
                tracksViewChanges: true
            }));
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.tron.log('Component Did update');
        if (this.state.tracksViewChanges) {
            this.setState(() => ({
                tracksViewChanges: false
            }));
        }
    }
    render() {
        let { clusterId, onPress, coordinate, data, clusteredPoints } = this.props;

        return (
            <Marker
                identifier={`cluster-${clusterId}`}
                coordinate={coordinate}
                onPress={onPress}
                tracksViewChanges={this.state.tracksViewChanges}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100
                    }}
                >
                    <Svg width={100} height={100}>
                        <PieChart style={{ height: 100 }} outerRadius={'100%'} innerRadius={'0%'} data={data} />
                        <View
                            style={{
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                position: 'absolute',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center'
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text
                                style={{
                                    color: 'white',
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    textAlignVertical: 'center'
                                }}
                            >
                                {clusteredPoints.length}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </Svg>
                </View>
            </Marker>
        );
    }
}
```

I am still having some issues with this. I am watching my console and it seems to be re-rendering constantly. The more zoomed in I am, the more it jumps around. It seems to be moving to different regions constantly, but I can't tell why it is doing that. Did I implement the tracksViewChanges properly?

Comment: With custom marker in `renderCluster`, you have to add `tracksViewChanges` and turn it off when you finish render in `PieChart `

Comment: I updated my answer above to show the new ClusterMarker.tsx file that I added, along with the tracksViewChanges. It is still jumping around a decent bit. Might seem a little bit better than before, but still seems to be constantly rendering the UI and moving the view/region constantly. Any ideas?